Ошибка при создании главного окна, после завершения работы Splash Screen'а
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from CryOlo import Ui_MainWindow 

class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self,*args, obj=None , **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.ends)
        
        self.timer.start(433)      
        

    def ends(self):
        
        self.counter += 1
        
        if self.counter >= 25:
            self.timer.stop()
             
            self.win = Olo()
            self.win.show()


            self.close()
#другой файлик, в котором находиться класс
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from Ui_CryOlo import ui_CryOlo

class Olo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ui_CryOlo ):

    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        

Первая часть кода пренадлежит splash scren'у и это все находиться в методе.
Почему когда я прошу создать нужное окно, оно создается пустым без ничего??

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

@aleksandrbarakin Вроде бы теперь нормально

Вопрос решен, я новичок, посему не особо владею пониманием всего. С помощью проб и ошибок я выяснил, что self.setupUi(self) нужен.
